# Issues with decoding two JSON feed sources and display with PHP/HTML

Tags: php, json

I am using two JSON feed sources and PHP to display a real estate property slideshow with agents on a website. The code was working prior to the feed provider making changes to where they store property and agent images. I have made the necessary adjustments for the images, but the feed data is not working now. I have contacted the feed providers about the issue, but they say the problem is on my end. No changes beyond the image URLs were made, so I am unsure where the issue may be. I am new to JSON, so I might be missing something. I have included the full script below. Here are the two JSON feed URLs: http://century21.ca/FeaturedDataHandler.c?DataType=4&EntityType=2&EntityID=2119 and http://century21.ca/FeaturedDataHandler.c?DataType=3&AgentID=27830&RotationType=1. The first URL grabs all of the agents and the second grabs a single agent's properties. The AgentID value is sourced from the JSON feed URL dynamically.

```
class Core
{

    private $base_url;
    private $property_image_url;
    private $agent_id;

    private $request_agent_properties_url;
    private $request_all_agents_url;

    private function formatJSON($json)
    {
        $from = array('Props:', 'Success:', 'Address:', ',Price:', 'PicTicks:', ',Image:', 'Link:', 'MissingImage:', 'ShowingCount:', 'ShowcaseHD:', 'ListingStatusCode:', 'Bedrooms:', 'Bathrooms:', 'IsSold:', 'ShowSoldPrice:', 'SqFootage:', 'YearBuilt:', 'Style:', 'PriceTypeDesc:');
        $to = array('"Props":', '"Success":', '"Address":', ',"Price":', '"PicTicks":', ',"Image":', '"Link":', '"MissingImage":', '"ShowingCount":', '"ShowcaseHD":', '"ListingStatusCode":', '"Bedrooms":', '"Bathrooms":', '"IsSold":', '"ShowSoldPrice":', '"SqFootage":', '"YearBuilt":', '"Style":', '"PriceTypeDesc":' );
        return str_ireplace($from, $to, $json); //returns the clean JSON

    }

    function __construct($agent=false)
    {
        $this->base_url  = 'http://www.century21.ca';
        $this->property_image_url = 'http://images.century21.ca';

        $this->agent_id = ($agent ? $agent : false);

        $this->request_all_agents_url =
            $this->base_url.'/FeaturedDataHandler.c?DataType=4&EntityType=3&EntityID=3454';

        $this->request_agent_properties_url =
            $this->base_url.'/FeaturedDataHandler.c?DataType=3'.'&AgentID='.$this->agent_id.'&RotationType=1';
    }

    /**
     * getSlides()
     */
    function getSlides()
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->request_all_agents_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        if (empty($response))
            return false;
        else
        $agents = $this->decode_json_string($response);

        // Loop Agents And Look For Requested ID
        foreach ($agents as $agent)
        {
            if (($this->agent_id != false) && (isset($agent['WTLUserID'])) && ($agent['WTLUserID'] != $this->agent_id))
            {
                continue; // You have specified a 
            }

            $properties = $this->getProperties($agent['WTLUserID']);

            $this->print_property_details($properties, $agent);
        }
    }

    /**
     * getProperties()
     */
    function getProperties($agent_id)
    {
        $url = $this->base_url.'/FeaturedDataHandler.c?DataType=3'.'&AgentID='.$agent_id.'&RotationType=1';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $json = json_decode($response);

        if (empty($response))
            die('No response 2'); //return false;
        else
            $json = $this->formatJSON($this->decode_json_string($response));

            var_dump($json);
            die();

            // return $json;
    }

    /**
     * print_property_details()
     */
    function print_property_details($properties, $agent, $html='')
    {
        $BASE_URL = $this->base_url;
        $PROPERTY_IMAGE_URL = $this->property_image_url;

        foreach ($properties as $property)
        {
            $img = $property['Image'];
            // $img = ($property['Image'] ? $property['Image'] : "some url to a dummy image here")

            if($property['ListingStatusCode'] != 'SOLD'){
                $address = $property['Address'];
                $shortaddr = substr($address, 0, -12);
                $html .= "<div class='listings'>";

                $html .= "<div class='property-image'>";
                $html .= "<img src='". $PROPERTY_IMAGE_URL ."' width='449' height='337' alt='' />";
                $html .= "</div>";
                $html .= "<div class='property-info'>";
                $html .= "<span class='property-price'>". $property['Price'] ."</span>";
                $html .= "<span class='property-street'>". $shortaddr ."</span>";
                $html .= "</div>";

                $html .= "<div class='agency'>";
                $html .= "<div class='agent'>";
                $html .= "<img src='". $agent['PhotoUrl']. "' class='agent-image' width='320' height='240' />";
                $html .= "<span class='agent-name'><b>Agent:</b>". $agent['DisplayName'] ."</span>";
                $html .= "</div>";
                $html .= "</div>";

                $html .= "</div>";
            }
        }
        echo $html;
    }

    function decode_json_string($json)
    {
        // Strip out junk
        $strip = array("{\"Agents\": [","{Props: ",",Success:true}",",\"Success\":true","\r","\n","[{","}]");
        $json = str_replace($strip,"",$json);

        // Instantiate array
        $json_array = array();

        foreach (explode("},{",$json) as $row)
        {
            /// Remove commas and colons between quotes
            if (preg_match_all('/"([^\\"]+)"/', $row, $match)) {
                foreach ($match as $m)
                {
                    $row = str_replace($m,str_replace(",","|comma|",$m),$row);
                    $row = str_replace($m,str_replace(":","|colon|",$m),$row);
                }
            }

            // Instantiate / clear array
            $array = array();

            foreach (explode(',',$row) as $pair)
            {
                $var = explode(":",$pair);

                // Add commas and colons back
                $val = str_replace("|colon|",":",$var[1]);
                $val = str_replace("|comma|",",",$val);
                $val = trim($val,'"');
                $val = trim($val);

                $key = trim($var[0]);
                $key = trim($key,'{');
                $key = trim($key,'}');

                $array[$key] = $val;
            }

            // Add to array
            $json_array[] = $array;
        }

        return $json_array;
    }
}
```

Comment: `json` on second url(Props) is not a valid `JSON`

Comment: can you update your question with latest code?

Comment: @Mubin I have updated the original question's code with your suggestions.

Comment: change this line `return $this->formatJSON($this->decode_json_string($response));` to `$json =  $this->formatJSON($this->decode_json_string($response)); return $json;`

also, please post a new link of your cleaned `json` from `formatJSON` method

Comment: I have made the change, but I am not sure what you mean by posting a new link. Do you want me to do a var_dump of the cleaned JSON and send you the link to the page?

Comment: @Mubin: I updated my code to show the var_dump. The result can be seen here: [link](http://imagineserver.ca/clients/century21westman/beta/slideshow/index.php).

Answer (score 0):

`JSON` on the second [URL](http://century21.ca/FeaturedDataHandler.c?DataType=3&AgentID=27830&RotationType=1#) is not a valid `JSON`, that's why you're not getting the reults, as `PHP` unable to `decode` that feed.

I tried to process it, and get this error

> Error: Parse error on line 1:
>   {Props: [{Address:"28
>   -^
>   Expecting 'STRING', '}'

Feed image for first URL

[image]

and here is view of 2nd URL's feed

[image]

as per error for second feed, all the `keys` should be wrapped within `"` as these are `strings` rather than `CONSTANTS`.

e.g.
`Props` should be `"Props"` and all other too.

**EDIT**

You need to update your `function`and add this one(`formatJSON($json)`) to your `class`

```
// Update this function, just need to update last line of function
function getProperties($agent_id)
{
    $url = $this->base_url.'/FeaturedDataHandler.c?DataType=3'.'&AgentID='.$agent_id.'&RotationType=1';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $json = json_decode($response);

    if (empty($response))
        die('No response 2'); //return false;
    else
        return $this->formatJSON($this->decode_json_string($response));    //this one only need to be updated.
}
//add this function to class. This will format json
private function formatJSON($json){
    $from= array('Props:', 'Success:', 'Address:', ',Price:', 'PicTicks:', ',Image:', 'Link:', 'MissingImage:', 'ShowingCount:', 'ShowcaseHD:', 'ListingStatusCode:', 'Bedrooms:', 'Bathrooms:', 'IsSold:', 'ShowSoldPrice:', 'SqFootage:', 'YearBuilt:', 'Style:', 'PriceTypeDesc:');
    $to = array('"Props":', '"Success":', '"Address":', ',"Price":', '"PicTicks":', ',"Image":', '"Link":', '"MissingImage":', '"ShowingCount":', '"ShowcaseHD":', '"ListingStatusCode":', '"Bedrooms":', '"Bathrooms":', '"IsSold":', '"ShowSoldPrice":', '"SqFootage":', '"YearBuilt":', '"Style":', '"PriceTypeDesc":' );
    return str_ireplace($from, $to, $json); //returns the clean JSON

}
```

**EDIT**

I've tested that function, and it's working fine, may be there is something wrong with your function `decode_json_string($json)`

I've taken unclean `json` from second URL, and cleaning it **[here](http://ideone.com/9opWKI)**, and putting that cleaned `json` in json editor to check either it's working or not **[HERE](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=acc65b66257bddc345ba71cd9aa43fb2)**

Comment: I was aware of the validation issue, but the feed provider has stated that it has always been invalid and that I would need to accommodate for it on my end. Is this even possible using PHP?

Comment: @MikeHermary: yes there is, I'm writing code for you, will update shortly.

Comment: @MikeHermary: I've update my answer. this is well tested and working code.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. I will test it later and let you know if it solves my issues.

Comment: I have updated the getProperties function and added the private function to the class, but it is not working for me. The updated code can be found here: [link](http://imagineserver.ca/clients/century21westman/beta/slideshow/index.php). Are there other edits that need to be completed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to fix the JSON:

```
$url = 'http://century21.ca/FeaturedDataHandler.c?DataType=3&AgentID=27830&RotationType=1';
$invalid_json = file_get_contents($url);
$json = preg_replace("/([{,])([a-zA-Z][^: ]+):/", "$1\"$2\":", $invalid_json);
var_dump($json);
```

All your keys need to be double-quoted